# why does my page load super slow?(has GeoJSON and Javascript content)

Tags: performance, d3.js, geojson, pagespeed

I made a data visualization using d3.js and here is the link: http://glennaxie.com/light-up-denver/

However, I've noticed the page loads very slow. It can take more than 20 seconds to allow the visualization to show up. Any suggestions for speeding it up?

Comment: The page requires to load a lot of data. You may get better performance with the smaller [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) format.

Comment: The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I cam across in your site Remove the following redirect chain if possible: http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js .